# Windows 8.1 Universal full width listview group header

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I am developing a windows universal 8.1 application .I need to full width header of listview. I use this code

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"  FontSize="17"  Foreground="Black" FontFamily="{StaticResource IranSans}" TextAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="ListViewBaseHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

but this code only works for windows phone 8.1 not windows 8.1. here is the image of them. does exist a way for windows 8.1?
[image: Windows 8.1]

[image: Windows Phone 8.1]

Comment: have you try get rid of that margin? maybe you can fix that!